# Python: Progress the index for a for loop

Tags: python, string, loops, indexing, iteration

Is there some way to move the index forward in a for loop in python?  For example, if I'm iterating through a string and find some char that I'm looking for, can I begin reading from that position on the next iteration of the for loop?

Like, after reading an x, read until a y and start from the position following the y on the next iteration:

```
for i in range(len(myString)):
  if myString[i] == 'x':
    j = i + 1
    while( myString[j] != '\n' ):
      if( myString[j] == 'y' ):
        i = j + 1  # start at position following y in string on the next iteration
      j = j + 1
```

Or do I have to use a while loop to achieve this?

Comment: I believe you'd have to use a `while` loop, or use the keyword `continue` in the case that you want to ignore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python arbitrarily incrementing an iterator inside a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474646/python-arbitrarily-incrementing-an-iterator-inside-a-loop)

Comment: Nope, definitely not a duplicate, @JGreenwell - none of the examples there deal with *reversing* an iterator

Comment: Okay, I guess a while loop it is.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Victor, I'll post an alternative approach

Comment: @ Wayne Werner Thanks.

Comment: Referring to Wayne's comment - you can't "reverse an iterator" in the general sense. You could seek to different positions in a list / file / etc, but that's a subset of things you can iterate over.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Readable, controllable iterators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734137/readable-controllable-iterators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using an infinite loop:

```
while true:
   if i >= len(myString): # Exit condition
      break

   # do something with myString[i]

   # set i as you want
```

Comment: @ Christian That's a nice alternative.  I'll give it a go.  Thanks.

Comment: I think that should be `if i >= len(myString)`.  Otherwise it goes out of bounds when `i == len(myString)`.  Otherwise, this works well for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an string instead of list in this sample code. It finds the first x in the remaining part of the list, then finds the first y after that 'x' and so on

```
#mylist = [list to search]
i = 0
while true:
    list_to_search = mylist[i:]
    if 'x' not in list_to_search:
        break
    j = list_to_search.index('x')
    if 'y' not in list_to_search[j+1:]:
        break
    i = list_to_search.index('y')
    (x_pos,y_pos)  = (j,i)
    #your code
```

Comment: @ alivar Nice.  I didn't think to use splicing.

Answer (score 1):

Now, effectively you're still using a `while` loop here - but I think this comes closer in spirit to what you were thinking about:

```
def myrange(limit=0):
    counter = 0
    while counter < limit:
        next = yield counter
        try:
            counter = int(next) - 1
        except TypeError:
            counter += 1    


mylist = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'five', 'four']       
my_iter = myrange(len(mylist))

for i in my_iter:
    print(mylist[i])
    if mylist[i] == 'five':
        print('-- three, sir! --')
        mylist[i] = 'three!'
        my_iter.send(i)
    elif mylist[i] == 'four':
        print("Don't count that number!")
```

This works because of the [`send`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#generator.send) function that generators have. They allow you to send a value to the generator that the generator can then use how it wishes. Note that when you call `.send()` on a generator that it will yield the next value (so when we call `my_iter.send(i)`, it's actually `yield`ing the next value. That's why we call `counter = int(next) - 1`. The alternative would be to put the `-1` in your `for` loop.

Comment: @ Wayne Werner I'm pretty new to python, so I think this example is a bit above my pay grade for now.  I'll definitely play around with it though.  Thanks for the feedback.